# What does the let mean in Java world?

Tags: java

I am wondering what does the `let` suffix mean in Java world?

I mean the `let` in `applet`, `servlet`, `facelet`, etc.

What is it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive#English

Comment: It means ["small"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-let).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is similar to that of booklet. A smaller part of an application: `applet`, a smaller component of a server application: `servlet`, and so on.

From Google definition:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

let - the diminutive suffix.
This is a non-independent software component that runs in the context of another, full-fledged application that is designed for one narrow task, and has no value in isolation from the base application.